# Successful Ajax call not returning data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to work on a simple Ajax call and I'm unable to figure out what's gone wrong. The ajax call is successful but nothing is alerting. When I console.log(myStats), it displays the JSON in my console though.

```
var main = function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0',
    success: function(data) {
        var myStats = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(myStats);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }

});

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: what output do you get

Comment: `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data))` you will get that alert.

Comment: What is output of console.log(data), Is it Object or string?

Comment: Just tip for a future: use a debugger rather than alerts. You wouldn't even ask this question then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse the response as it's already a JSON.  Though ajax should automatically know this, just to be sure you can set `dataType` explicitly.  Also, you can't really `alert()` a json object.

```js
var main = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      // do things with data here.. this for instance
      var html = jsonToHtml(data);
      $('#output tbody').html(html);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
};

function jsonToHtml(data) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === 'object') {
      html += jsonToHtml(v)
    } else {
      html += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v + "</td></tr>";
    }
  });
  return html;
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="output">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>KEY</th>
      <th>VALUE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function main(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0',
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
    };

    $(document).ready(main);
```

Instead of success call back, use Deferred object.

for success use **.done().**

this works.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `done()`, but what's wrong with the `success` callback?